# Domain name masking for django webapp Ask

Tags: domain, django, saas, digital-ocean

I have a website with the domain address: www.example.com. We are providing a SaaS solution.

The issue is we are facing a demand from some clients & that is domain name masking, i.e. the client wants to access my website from www.client1website.com & www.client2website.com & so on....

Is there any option that would be possible in Django? I dont want to change the Allowed Host thing as that would make the service non-scalable.

FYI: I am using Apache as of now & can also move to nginx of needed.

Comment: What is the "Allowed Host thing"?

Comment: If they want to use TLS, then there needs to be a certificate matching their domain name. I

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Apache (or nginx) to listen to any domain name you want, either a number of specific domain names or a blank wildcard of *all* domain names. This is even the default.

If you then want to have different branding depending on the domain name or react in other ways to the domain, you would have to do this in the Django app, the requested domain name will be listed in the request object. But this is [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) here.